# unable to read csv data using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

using this print i'm getting this output

```
print(price_data['sellingPrice'])
#0    500
#1    300
#Name: sellingPrice, dtype: int64

print(price_data['orders'])

#0    1000
#1      12
#Name: orders, dtype: int64

sale_value=  (((price_data['sellingPrice']) * (price_data['orders'])))

#0    500000
#1      3600
#dtype: int64 sale_value
```

is there any way that i can get output like this

for 1st row of csv

```
price_data['sellingPrice']=500
price_data['orders']=100
sale_value=500000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price_data['sale_value']=price_data['sellingPrice'] * price_data['orders']
```

Then Just use this:-

```
price_data.loc[0,['sellingPrice','orders','sale_value']]
```

Comment: ```  sellingPrice  productCost  ...  weightSegment  avgRtoCharge
0           500          350  ...            420           130

[1 rows x 10 columns]``` gives this output